# Video is not playing using link in VideoView

Tags: java, android, html

All the code here is fine, but through the link I used no videos can be viewed. No videos can be viewed on my apps.

[This Code is Run. Then Result Is. See This Image on Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RztTg.jpg)

XML:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/VideoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can not working both also code. Result is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RztTg.jpg

JAVA:

```java
public class VideoViewActivity extends Activity {

    // Declare variables
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    VideoView videoview;
    Button button;

    // Insert your Video URL

    String VideoURL = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapplication-93934.appspot.com/o/4zHm_6AQ7CY_mp4-hd.mp4?alt=media&token=a31e1e60-7104-4060-8112-1527ab58fe3a";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.videoview_main);
        videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);


        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoViewActivity.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Android Video Streaming Tutorial");
        pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        pDialog.show();

        try {

            MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                    VideoViewActivity.this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
            Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
            videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            videoview.setVideoURI(video);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        videoview.requestFocus();
        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                videoview.start();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the INTERNET permission into your manifest file if you haven't put it.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

and try this code

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class VideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String VideoURL = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapplication-93934.appspot.com/o/4zHm_6AQ7CY_mp4-hd.mp4?alt=media&token=a31e1e60-7104-4060-8112-1527ab58fe3a";
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    VideoView videoview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

        videoview=findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoActivity.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Android Video Streaming Tutorial");
        pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        pDialog.show();

        videoview.setVideoPath(VideoURL);

        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                videoview.start();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: You can tick it if you are satisfied @JannatunFariya